# rails openssl different results of encryption from code and terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, openssl

when I try to encrypt data from terminal like

```
echo -n "TestData" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -K C81E728D9D4C2F636F067F89CC14862C65990ABE58735B91B6B8798E8CE45F22 -iv D342F9C6310F6B21E97AB38595BD8CAA
```

than the Base64 encoded result I receive is

**VJwJBTtVntJvRGkD24S4wg==**

But when I try same thing with rails using exactly same key and initialization vector

```
    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')
    cipher.encrypt
    cipher.key = "C81E728D9D4C2F636F067F89CC14862C65990ABE58735B91B6B8798E8CE45F22"
    cipher.iv = "D342F9C6310F6B21E97AB38595BD8CAA"
    encrypted_data = cipher.update("TestData")
    encrypted_data << cipher.final
    Base64.strict_encode64(encrypted_data)
```

than I receive entirely different Base64 encoded result

**qavpNrU7llgauAyyEZz/bw==**

can someone point that what I missed?

Comment: Note: 1. `98304A2480DDC0FA354278936DAC2A0D7D9074650AD6` is an invalid key size, AES keys are 128, 192 or 256 bits in length (16, 24 or 32 bytes). Since it appears the key should be 256-bits (32-bytes) the missing key bytes will be either garbage or possibly nulls, key extension is undefined. Thus different results.

Comment: I updated question with key generated by openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pass pass:my_random_password -nosalt -p -in testFile -out testFile.enc

Comment: didn't get what you are asking, I updated complete answer with keys & resuts

Comment: I am using same keys from terminal and code, not getting that what part you are saying is incorrect

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice you changed the IV as well. Corrected [AESCALC](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc?key=C81E728D9D4C2F636F067F89CC14862C65990ABE58735B91B6B8798E8CE45F22&iv=D342F9C6310F6B21E97AB38595BD8CAA&input=54657374446174610808080808080808&mode=cbc&action=Encrypt&output=48C85F1FF343CF080211B2A2C8C83319). where the encrypted data in Base64: `VJwJBTtVntJvRGkD24S4wg==` which matches the first example. So the best guess is that you are not specifying the inputs in the correct form to the second example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provide the `key` and `iv` attributes as hex strings, but the expected format is raw bytes. Converting them to binary yields the expected result, with the following script:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

def hex_to_bin(s)
 s.scan(/../).map { |x| x.hex.chr }.join
end

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')
cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = hex_to_bin("C81E728D9D4C2F636F067F89CC14862C65990ABE58735B91B6B8798E8CE45F22")
cipher.iv = hex_to_bin("D342F9C6310F6B21E97AB38595BD8CAA")
encrypted_data = cipher.update("TestData")
encrypted_data << cipher.final
puts Base64.strict_encode64(encrypted_data)
```

(Source for the `hex_to_bin` function: [To Hex and Back (With Ruby)](https://anthonylewis.com/2011/02/09/to-hex-and-back-with-ruby/)).

Calling it `encrypt.rb`, this is the result of running it:

```
$ ruby encrypt.rb 
encrypt.rb:8: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
VJwJBTtVntJvRGkD24S4wg==
```

To get rid of the "is deprecated" warning I had to [replace the deprecated class `OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher` with  `OpenSSL::Cipher`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher/Cipher.html).

Answer (score 0):

The key is to short, `98304A2480DDC0FA354278936DAC2A0D7D9074650AD6` is an invalid key size, AES keys are 128, 192 or 256 bits in length (16, 24 or 32 bytes). Since it appears the key should be 256-bits (32-bytes) the missing key bytes will be either garbage or possibly nulls, key extension is undefined. Thus different results.

Assuming null padding and PKCS#7 padding for the first case the result is correct:
[AESCALC](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc?key=98304A2480DDC0FA354278936DAC2A0D7D9074650AD600000000000000000000&iv=5B2481F855265171E0A11CF36D076606&input=54657374446174610808080808080808&mode=cbc&action=Encrypt&output=)

The second example is filling out the key in some other manor.

The solution is to use a full length key.

Comment: Note: The question has been changed.